# Optional Invalid Query String Variables

Tags: asp.net

This is a somewhat philosophical issue. I have a .net (but could be any platform) based helper library that parses query string values. Take for example a variable that returns an Int32: my framework has an option that specifies whether this value is required or optional. If it is required but not provided, the framework throws an exception. If it is optional and not specified, it returns a null.

Now an edge case has come up based on users hacking (in a good way) our urls. If they specify a variable with either an invalidly formatted Int32 ("&ID=abc") or provide the variable but not specify a value ("&id="), should the framework throw an exception or should it return a null?

Part of me feels that invalid variables or formats should return a null. It might be valid to argue that even if the parameter is optional, an invalidly formatted query string or value should still throw an exception.

Thoughts?

Comment: When you say your framework are you talking about ASP.NET or your own web application?

Comment: I have my own framework.

Comment: All of these malformed URLs are the result of users "hacking" things. All of this is on our intranet and we do allow some deep linking so the hacking isn't an issue on its own. But if you are going to hack a url and provide an invalid int for an ID ("&id=abc") should that throw an exception? The more I think about it, the more I think the answer to that is yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this is philophical ...

On something like an ID, I would agree with Shawn that it is a 404, especially if you are thinking in terms of state. There is no object, so not found. But, ID may not tie directly to a resource in all cases.

If the item is truly optional, a null is okay. But optional should mean "if present it makes the call more specific" in this case and there should always be a fallback. I don't see this in ID, unless the ID is keyed to an optional part of the page.

In the long run, I think you should look at the business reason for the page and what each variable means.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that if a variable is optionaly, providing the variable but not specifying the value is equivalent to ommitting the variable itself. In this case, returning null seems OK.

However, providing an invalidly formatted value ought to cause an Exception, since the *intent* was to provide a value. In this case the user ought to be notified through some sort of validation mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

A HttpException of 404 (Not Found). Your web application framework should know how to catch these errors and redirect to the proper page.

This is actually a not found error because the resources that the ID is pointing to does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect there's no "right" answer to your question.  If I were a developer using your library, I would expect/hope that the public API would include in its code comments, a description of how the function behaves when the URL param includes bad (wrong type) data.

You might also be able to craft your public API to get the best of both worlds: .NET seems to have adopted the "Parse" / "TryParse" approach in many places.  If I'm the caller and I want the function to throw if given invalid data, I call Parse().  If I don't want it to throw, I call TryParse().  In my opinion, that is a nice pattern to follow with your API as well.